# How can I compute the intersection between two arrays that may contain duplicate elements?

Tags: perl

How can I compute the intersection (the common elements) of two arrays? I tried with this code:

```
my @array1 = (1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4);
my @array2 = (2, 3, 4, 4, 4);
my %original = ();
my @isect = ();

map { $original{$_} = 1 } @array1;
@isect = grep { $original{$_} } @array2;

print "@isect\n";
```

The result is `2 3 4 4 4`, but I want to get `2 3 4`.

Another example:

```
@array1 = (5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1, 4);
@array2 = (5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4);
```

This should return `5 6 7 7 7 4`, not `5 6 7 6 7 7 4 4 4`. How can I do this?

Comment: `map` is for "mapping" one list into another. Your statement `map { $original{$_} = 1 } @array1` misuses it by creating a new list and then discarding it. The correct way would be `$original{$_} = 1 for @array1` or `my %original = map { $_ => 1 } @array1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
my @array1 = ( 5, 6, 7,    7, 7, 1, 4       );
my @array2 = ( 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7,    4, 4, 4 );

my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @array1;
my @common = grep { --$counts{$_} >= 0 } @array2;

say "@common";  # 5 6 7 7 7 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`perldoc perlfaq4` has the answer

[*How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f)

This is the multi-purpose code it offers

```
my (@union, @intersection, @difference);

my %count = ();

foreach my $element (@array1, @array2) {
    $count{$element}++
}

foreach my $element (keys %count) {
    push @union, $element;
    push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your first example, you've eliminated duplicate elements in the desired output.  In your second, you haven't - I don't even understand the desired result. :(  Therefore, I'll fix the problem for what you say you wanted for the first example output.

Changing:

```
@isect = grep { $original{$_} } @array2;
```

to:

```
@isect = grep { exists $original{$_} and   $original{$_}++ < 2 } @array2;
```

produces:

2 3 4  for the first example

and

5 6 7 4  for the second example.

test code:

```
my @array1 = (1, 2, 3,3,3,3,4);
my @array2 = (2, 3, 4,4,4);

print intersect( \@array1, \@array2);

@array1 = (5,6,7,7,7,1,4);
@array2 = (5,6,7,6,7,7,4,4,4);

print intersect( \@array1, \@array2);


sub intersect {
    my ($first, $second) = @_;
    my @array1 = @{ $first };
    my @array2 = @{ $second };
    my %original = ();
    my @isect = ();
    map { $original{$_} = 1 } @array1;
    @isect = grep { exists $original{$_} and   $original{$_}++ < 2 } @array2;
    return "@isect\n";
    }
```

Comment: There are three 7s in each array in the second example, so they want the result to also contain three 7s.

Comment: You shouldn't be needlessly copying those arrays, you shouldn't assign empty lists to already empty variables, that first `map` should be a `for` loop, and the output formatting (the `"@isect\n"`) should be done outside the sub. This gives `my %original; $original{$_} = 1 for @$first; return grep { exists $original{$_} and   $original{$_}++ < 2 } @$second;`, which would be better written as `my %original = map { $_ => 1 } @$first; my return grep { delete($original{$_}) } @$second;`. But like ThisSuitIsBlackNot mentioned, this isn't what the OP needs.

Comment: ikegami: I was trying to make my routine look as much like the originall as possible.   but since I didn't really understand the question, I should not have bothered.  sorry to waste bandwidth.